# How to show a part of the circle using custom painter?

Tags: flutter, dart, geometry, custom-painter, flutter-custompaint

So I have this card widget to create
[image]

how can I create the golden part of the circle using custom painter?.I can create a full circle but how can I just display that small part of the circle and hide the rest?

```
Card(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                      child: Text(
                          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cursus sed eros ullamcorper.")),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text("*Conditions Apply"),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.pink,
              width: 200,
              height: 300,
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: ArcPainter(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )));
```

Comment: you need a `ClipPath`, not `CustomPaint` - in your case the child of `ClipPath` would be `Image.asset` / `Image.network` etc

Comment: Although not an answer to your question... since you will surely not hand-paint the hand and sale sign in a custompaint in flutter, why not just include the golden circle in the picture you will need to use anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ArcShape` using the [shape_of_view](https://pub.dev/packages/shape_of_view_null_safe)  package.

```
ShapeOfView(
  shape: ArcShape(
    direction: ArcDirection.Outside,
    height: 20,
    position: ArcPosition.Bottom
  ),
  child: ...
)
```